# Can't read from sdcard even with storage permissions

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions

Basically, I'm making an application that sends one file on a phone to another. So for example, phone A will connect to a server, upload a file, and the server will send that file to phone B. This is all on android. I've made a socket server which works. However, every time I try to send a file, I cannot open it due to permissions being denied:

```
android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I have added the permissions to the manifest (inside the `<manifest></manifest>` tags):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And I have also asked for permissions in `onCreate()` :

```
    public static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    };
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
        this,
        PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
        REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    );
```

I have also tried using run-time permission and still no luck. For some reason, this works on my Oneplus 8T, but not on any other android phone (maybe I messed with the developper settings too much). Stuck on what to do now. I first struggled in getting the path from the URI but now I have figured that out, I have the permissions issue. Any help is appreciated, and I can upload all the code if need be.

Comment: "I first struggled in getting the path from the URI but now I have figured that out" -- a `Uri` is not a file. Unless the `Uri` has the `file` scheme, there is no guaranteed mapping from the `Uri` to some filesystem path that you will be able to read or write. You also have less filesystem access on Android 10+ as part of scoped storage.

Comment: Please try to use scoped storage for read and write in above 10 version , till 10 you can add legacy external store attribute in manifest application tag

Answer (score 0):

Comments did not help- what I found is that I needed to ask for permissions every time I was opening the app. This is because the android versions I was using were very different and so did not work the same depending on which version I used.
Here is the code I put in the onCreate method:

```
public static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
};

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
            REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
```

I also have the `<uses-permission>` tags for both read and write in external storage inside of the AndroidManifest file. Hope this helps someone in the future.